# Archive section for objects in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to customize `Django Admin` to have specific section for `objects` of my models (Such as `Post` or `Product` models) that use as an archive section.

I now that, I need one field in my models that shown status of objects (Such as `is_archive` field), but **I don't have any idea about how to display them in `Django Admin`.**

**Does anyone have an opinion on this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create [Proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for model you need
2. Create separate section in your admin panel for this proxy model
3. Override [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) for it.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    is_archive = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    ...

class PostProxy(Post):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

@admin.register(PostProxy)
class PostProxyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).filter(is_archive=True)
```

Comment: Nice! @wearestardust